# Using mixin function on returns function, not the value of function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a mixin that I'm trying to import to another file and use the function from, however when I do I either get undefined or it returns the function altogether. I just want to receive the value from the function in the other file.

```
mixin/isSessionActive.js

export default function isSessionActive({ app, store }) {
  return 'something'
}
```

```
anotherfile.js

import isSessionActive from '~/mixins/isSessionActive'

export default ({ app, env, redirect, store }, inject) => {
....code ....

console.log('isSessionActive', isSessionActive) 
})
```

The console.log above returns:

```
isSessionActive 
function isSessionActive(_ref)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but it looks like you just need to call the function. `console.log('isSessionActive', isSessionActive({ app, store }))`

Answer (score 0):

As @skirtle mentionned: You imported the function, not the result of it. So you have to use `isSessionActive({ app, store })` to get the result

Comment: Ok, I thought I could just call it and the app and store would get passed along automatically like most of the functions through the application. Is there a way to remove the need to pass app and store through everywhere I use it?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Maybe with a Nuxt plugin you could automatically inject this value into the context, but I'm not sure it's possible and I don't know how to do it, sorry!